# Bootstrap carousal padding conflict with .well class

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I am using bootstrap carousal. When I add the well class, padding becomes an issue. The hidden slides does not have the padding. Padding is applied as soon as the slide becomes visible. This gives an undesirable "slide down" effect". See below link.

http://www.bootply.com/RppJN29MXc

I am using the standard `.well` class from bootstrap.

Comment: move the .well class up a level to the #myCarousel div element

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're only applying the well to the inner content of the carousel, not the carousel itself.

If you move the `well` class to the actual carousel container, where you have classes `carousel` and `slide`, it'll apply it to the entire carousel and you won't have that weird "flicker".

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide well">
  <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
      <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>

    <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div class="item active">
        <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080&amp;text=Slide One');"></div>
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Modern Business - A Bootstrap 3 Template</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080&amp;text=Slide Two');"></div>
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Ready to Style &amp; Add Content</h1>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="item">
        <div class="fill" style="background-image:url('http://placehold.it/1900x1080&amp;text=Slide Three');"></div>
        <div class="carousel-caption">
          <h1>Additional Layout Options at <a href="http://startbootstrap.com">http://startbootstrap.com</a></h1>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Controls -->
    <a class="left carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="icon-prev"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="right carousel-control" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="icon-next"></span>
    </a>
</div>
</div>
```

**[BOOTPLY](http://www.bootply.com/wGPO9Nnxri)**